# Get List of (Parents) from Child

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

```
public class Folder
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Folder> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I have a recursive tree, however, depending on some folders i need to go back and add a (state) to the parent folders.

While I am creating the child folders within the parent folder, i can update the previous level no problem. I am however having trouble going back more levels... So lets say for example..

```
1 Appliances NULL (Active)
2 TV 1 (Active)
3 Radio 1 (Active)
4 Furniture NULL (Active)
5 Chair 4 (Active)
6 Sofa 4 (Active)
7 Specials 4 (Active)
8 Golden Sofa 7 (Not Active)
```

Lets say that i need to go back to Specials, and make it not active, that's okay I have no problem, but i need to go back to specials parent (furniture) and make it not active as well....

C# Help Please!

I wouldn't mind using LINQ not sure how to do it though.... 
MERCI!

Comment: seems a job to a composite pattern, plz post your recursive implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your class to this

```
public class Folder
{
    public Folder Parent{get;set;}
    public int ID { get; set; }
    private List<Folder> children { get; set; }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Folder> Children { get { return children.AsReadOnly();}
    public void AddChildern(Folder child)
    {
       child.Parent = this;
       children.Add(child);
    }

    public void RemoveChildren(Folder child)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

So you can traverse through your folders forward or backward and then with a simple recursive function you can go top n-level

For example you want to find a node in parents, you can do it by this method

```
public Folder FindInParentsByID(Folder node,int ID)
{
   if (node.Parent == null)
     return null;
   if (node.Parent.ID == ID)
     return node.Parent;
   else
     return FindInParentByID(node.Parent,ID)
}
```

or if you want all parents you can do it by this method

```
public void FetchAllParents(Folder node, List<Folder> parentlist)
{
  if (node.Parent == null)
     return;

  parentlist.Add(node.Parent);
  FetchAllParents(node.Parent, parentList);
}
```

and you create an empty list and pass it to the method

Comment: Okay, i can change the class but how exactly do I iterate backwards from a child node?

Comment: But is there a way to get a list of parents? or do i have to iterate through each?

Comment: FetchAllParents will get you all the parent  to the List<Folder> you insert to parameter , 

List<Folder> parentlist = new List<Folder>();
FetchAllParents ( yourCurrentTargetNode , parentlist );

// now  parentlist  will have list of  parents.

ps. recursive function is already iterate process.